# Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController does not exist in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created a multi auth in Laravel 5.3,

Then moved `Controller/Auth/[files]` to:

Admin: `Controller/Admin/Auth/[files]` &

Site: `Controller/Site/Auth/[files]`

In command line I type `php artisan route:list`,

It shows me following error:

> Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController does not exist

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to manually define all the `Auth` routes in `web.php` and remove `Auth::routes()`.

just define all your routes like,

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answer.

Comment: @Ali If you find my answer helpful and it  works for you then accept and  upvote it so it help others

Comment: How to call in balde? `Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');`

Comment: if you need to display your own login form then you need to override `showLoginForm()` in your `Admin\Auth\LoginController` and write like this `public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.login');
    }`

Comment: No! how to create click? for example this code not work -> <a href="{{ Route('login') }}">Login</a>, I use without group for `Site/Auth\...`

Comment: just use `URL` helper like `<a href="{{ URL::to('admin/login')}}">Login</a>`

Comment: Laravel 5.8, I keep `Auth::routes();` and add a new "login" route like `Route::post('/login/xxx', 'Auth\LoginController@yyy')->name('zzz');`

Answer (score 2):

The two default authentication controllers provided with the framework have been split into four smaller controllers. The easiest way to upgrade your application to the new authentication controllers is to grab a fresh copy of each controller from GitHub and place them into your application.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.3/app/Http/Controllers/Auth

You should also make sure that you are calling the Auth::routes() method in your  routes/web.php file. This method will register the proper routes for the new authentication controllers.

Pasted this answer from the Laravel upgrade documentation.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had the same issue when I type: `php artisan route:list`

As I am using **Laravel 8.x**, I noticed there is a tiny change in the notations which I had to apply in **routes/web.php** in 2 steps:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController; // step 1

Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'login']); // step 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're moving controllers to a custom directory, you shouldn't use auth routes. So remove this from routes file:

If you're using 5.2

```
Route::auth();
```

If you're using 5.3

```
Auth::routes();
```

And then build auth routes manually.

Answer (score 1):

for me just i'am add `Auth::routes();` in my routes file `routes/web.php` or any other routes file like `routes/admin.php` if you create it

Answer (score 0):

Hello please check your route/web.php

```
/* For get login page*/
    Route::get('/login', function () {return view('auth.login');});

 /* while post remember to user Auth\controllername so you can get the perfect path for the custom login  */
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@authentication')->name('login');
```

Answer (score 0):

It Happens With Me Now And I Had Solved It By Another Way

Simply Copy The Auth Folder
And Put It In The Path Of Admin Controllers Folder

And Open Each File And Change

*namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;*

**To**

*namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\Auth;*

> Hope It Just Helps Somebody

Comment: Why should one randomly change namespaces?

Answer (score -2):

add this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Comment: While this may answer the user's question, adding an explanation will help improve the quality of this answer and help other users understand your solution.

Answer (score -3):

Download or copy RegisterController.php from another project.
Paste it in your project under

> Controllers/Auth/[files]

That's it